# Setting filename as a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to set the filename as a variable in a batch file and having no luck.

As a simple explanation I was attempting to name my file as an IPv4 address, e.g. `192.168.1.15.bat`. Then when running the file it would set that address as `var1` to be used in various places throughout the script.

```
@echo off
set var1=%~n1
echo %var1%
pause
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54956790/edit) to clarify, your task. Are you passing a single filename, `device.bat`, to your script, and wanting that filename without extension, `device`, to be displayed in the `cmd.exe` window? Can you explain how you're passing that argument/parameter? what happens when you do? and what you've tried yourself in fixing the issue? BTW, the preferred syntax for setting a variable is `Set "var1=%~n1"`.

Comment: phifer2088, I have chaged your irrelevant title, removed the irrelevant tags, and rewrote/corrected your question body, to clarify matters. As such, you can now delete the comment above, as its content has been placed in the question body, _where it belongs_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `%~n0`, `%0` is the batch file itself:

```
@echo off
set var1=%~n0
echo %var1%
pause
```

`%1` and after are for other parameters of the batch file, for example,
`tt.cmd`:

```
@echo off
::add quotes is recommended, to avoid error when there're special characters exist.
set "var0=%~n0"
set "var1=%~n1"
set "var2=%~n2"
echo %var0%
echo %var1%
echo %var2%
```

Run on prompt:

```
>tt.cmd what ever
tt
what
ever
```

Or `call` from another batch file, e.g. `cc.cmd`:

```
@call tt.cmd que sera sera
@pause >nul
```

Output:

```
tt
que
sera
```

You can check `call /?` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
@echo off
echo %~n0
pause
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.